# WCF web service sending JSON from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vb.net, wcf

Hey all I am in need of some help with my current code. I am wanting to send the value **2767994111** to my WCF web service via the jQuery AJAX call.

```
var parameter = { value: "2767994111" };

$('#btSubmit').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/",
      data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);
      }
   });
});
```

**IService1.vb**

```
<ServiceContract> _
Public Interface IService1
    <OperationContract> _
    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetData/{value}", RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)> _
    Function getEmpData(value As String) As String
End Interface
```

**Service1.svc**

```
Public Class Service1
    Public Class Clocked
        Public Property [date]() As String
            Get
                Return m_date
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_date = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_date As String

        Public Property type() As String
            Get
                Return m_type
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_type = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_type As String
    End Class

    Public Class DATA
        Public Property firstName() As String
            Get
                Return m_firstName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_firstName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_firstName As String

        Public Property lastName() As String
            Get
                Return m_lastName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_lastName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_lastName As String

        Public Property emailAddress() As String
            Get
                Return m_emailAddress
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_emailAddress = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_emailAddress As String

        Public Property phoneNum() As String
            Get
                Return m_phoneNum
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_phoneNum = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_phoneNum As String

        Public Property image() As String
            Get
                Return m_image
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_image = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_image As String

        Public Property title() As String
            Get
                Return m_title
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_title = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_title As String

        Public Property clocked() As List(Of Clocked)
            Get
                Return m_clocked
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of Clocked))
                m_clocked = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_clocked As List(Of Clocked)
    End Class

    Public Class RootObject
        Public Property DATA() As DATA
            Get
                Return m_DATA
            End Get
            Set(value As DATA)
                m_DATA = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_DATA As DATA
    End Class

    Public Function getEmpData(phoneNum As String) As String
        Try
            Dim connetionString As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=stantecUsers;Integrated Security=True"
            Dim sql As String = (Convert.ToString("SELECT * " + "FROM [stantecUsers].[dbo].[users] AS stantecUsers " + "INNER JOIN [stantecUsers].[dbo].[usersData] AS stantecUserData " + "ON stantecUsers.link2Data = stantecUserData.link2Data " + "WHERE stantecUsers.phoneNum = '") & phoneNum) + "' " + "ORDER BY stantecUsers.ID ASC;"
            Dim connection As SqlConnection
            Dim command As SqlCommand
            connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

            ' Create a new object that matches the structure of the JSON file.
            Dim root = New RootObject() With { _
                 .DATA = New DATA() With { _
                .clocked = New List(Of Clocked)() _
                } _
            }

            Try
                connection.Open()
                command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                Dim read As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

                While read.Read()
                    root.DATA.firstName = read("firstName").ToString()
                    root.DATA.lastName = read("lastName").ToString()
                    root.DATA.phoneNum = read("phoneNum").ToString()
                    root.DATA.title = read("title").ToString()
                    root.DATA.emailAddress = read("emailAddress").ToString()
                    root.DATA.image = read("image").ToString()
                    root.DATA.clocked.Add(New Clocked() With { _
                        .[date] = read("theDate").ToString(), _
                        .type = read("theType").ToString() _
                    })
                End While

                read.Close()
                command.Dispose()
                connection.Close()

                Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.WriteLine("Can not open connection! " + ex.Message)
                Return "Can not open connection! " + ex.Message
            End Try
        Catch e As SqlException
            Return e.Message
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="httpbind" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="Wcf.App.Service1"  behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="httpbind"
                  contract="Wcf.App.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="web">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The error that I am receiving is:

> GET
>   http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/?{%22value%22:%222767994111%22}
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm not really sure where to go from here in order to fix this so any help would be great!

**UPDATE FOR @Darin Dimitrov**

**html page:**

```
var parameter = { value: "2767994111" };

$('#btSubmit').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/" + parameter.value,
      data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus);
      }
   });
});
```

**Going to *http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/2767994111*:**

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Service1.svc/GetData/2767994111

Answer (score 0):

It  makes no sense to specify `application/json` content type when making a GET request because the body of the request is empty. Also don't `JSON.stringify` but rather send the value in the url as the service expects:

```
var parameter = { value: "2767994111" };

$('#btSubmit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/" + parameter.value,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

It looks like your `Service1` class doesn't implement the `IService1` interface which is the reason why you are getting those 404s. So make sure that you properly implement the service interface:

```
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Function getEmpData(phoneNum As String) As String Implements IService1.getEmpData
        ... snip
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Still did not work. I get **GET http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/2767994111 500 (Internal Server Error)** now.

Comment: **(anonymous function)** on the AJAX.

Comment: The problem is that your `Service1` class doesn't implement the `IService1` service contract. I have updated my answer to illustrate how to do that. After properly implementing the service contract you should be able to directly type the following url in your browser and receive the expected result: `http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/2767994111`. Also I would really recommend you setting up only the skeleton of the service and testing that it works before doing the actual implementation of the method. This way it's much easier to debug and isolate problems.

Comment: No error this time when adding that but no data either. Its just a blank page. Even when i tell it to output a bogus data it's still a blank page?

Comment: Did you remove all implementation details from your `getEmpData` method and just did an empty `Return "FooBar"` statement in it? After you did this, did you type the `http://localhost:65234/Service1.svc/GetData/2767994111` url in your browser address bar?

Comment: Yep just that simple and its just a blank page.

Comment: Strange, I am unable to replicate this issue. I have created a new ASP.NET application and added a WCF service with the exact same code of the `IService1` interface as shown in your question and the exact same code as `Service1` implementation as shown in my answer and it worked perfectly fine when I requested the GET method in the browser. I also used the exact same `web.config` as shown in your question. So maybe you should try in a blank new project.

Comment: Of course that I can, here you go: http://wikisend.com/download/354086/SampleWCF.zip Once you have downloaded, open the solution in VS2015, run the web application and navigate to `http://localhost:5533/Service1.svc/GetData/123`. You will be greeted with the respective response. Now that you have a working WCF service it's trivial to add the client side jQuery part to consume it using an AJAX GET request.